# Regex - Skip first 12 characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

How can I use regex to skip the lines with the text added or deleted and match text after the first 12 characters? For example,

```
1234567890ABTest
ABC4567890ABTestadded
ABC4567890ABTest2
```

Line 1 would match Test. Line 2 would not match. Line 3 would match Test2. So far, I have

```
.*(?<!added)(?<!deleted)$
```

Comment: `\w{12}` should work. what about `\w` 12 times ?

Comment: What version of Notepad++ are you using?

Comment: I'm now using v6.4.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
^.{12}\KTest(?!(?:added|deleted)\b).*$
```

You can use `\K` to skip first `12` characters.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/25

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, any characters (number of characters) can appear between 13th character and the end of the line or added deleted.

Comment: @James `^.{12}\KTest(?!.*(?:added|deleted)\b).*$` try this

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
^.{12}(.*)(?<!added)(?<!deleted)$
```

`pattern{X}` matches `pattern` repeated `X` times.
`pattern{X,Y}` matches `pattern` repeated `X` to `Y` times.
`pattern{X,}` matches `pattern` at least `X`.
`pattern{,Y}` matches `pattern` up to `Y` times.

Comment: My application (Notepad++) doesn't allow {12}. If type twelve dot (.) in place of the {12} it selects the entire line.

Comment: According to [their documentation](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions), they support the full range of Perl regex syntax. I can also confirm it works on my copy. Are you on the most recent version? Are you using the find dialog properly? When asking questions involving regular expressions, many engines differ, so you should *always* specify which engine you are using.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated to to v6.4.3 and the {12} is now permitted. However, the entire line is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Notepad++ v5.7

Consider removing everything with the following patterns: `^............`, `.+added$` and  `.+deleted$`

Everything else is the expected result.

Don't forget to replace in `Regular Expression` mode.